# Moore-Penrose question

Tags: matrix-theory

Let $A=BD^{\dagger}B^{T}$. I am looking for conditions under which $A^{\dagger}$ is a "nice" expression in $B$ and $D$ and their Moore-Penrose pseudo-inverses.

Do you know of such conditions?

Comment: Felix, a reverse order law for the triple product might give some nice answer. For instance, see R. Hartwig, The reverse order law revisited, Linear Algebra Appl., 76 (1986), 241-246.


Comment: @SJ: Thanks a lot, this looks very relevant. Maybe you would like to write this as an answer so I can accept it?